# Xampp not rendering PHP on custom project

Tags: php, windows, macos, xampp

I use two machines for Dev, my Mac for my primary work, emails and some small projects when I'm on the move but primarily use RDP and run XAMPP and Vis Studio on my PC. I have XAMPP installed on my Mac using a bundled XAMPP installer.

This PC has XAMPP, MySQL, IIS and MSSQL installed and runs my Wordpress sites perfectly, custom plugins work great however I recently created a custom project from scrach on my MAC and when I wanted to move it to my dev machine (for source control etc) I found that XAMPP wouldn't run the site as a "PHP" site. The pages show selective portions of php code, even stranger is that I will get syntax errors when I intentionally break code on pages yet a simple "echo" won't work as expected. Bear in mind that my Wordpress installs run perfectly at the same time as this project gives issues.

Frustrated, I uploaded my project to my hosting provider to see how the project would render and to my dismay, the project ran perfectly, my hosting provider runs linux machines so I wonder if there's a possibility something in my code isn't working on the windows XAMPP distribution.

How do I start trying to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your new project in by creating an alias in XAMPP config file namely httpd-xampp.conf

```
Alias /newproject "C:/xampp/newproject/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/newproject">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then you could browse like this

http://localhost:{port as you are using IIS}/newproject/

Comment: Sorry, that hasn't made a difference. I don't see why I should have to do this, my project is located within the htdocs folder so theoretically it should be parsed as PHP & since it throws syntax errors, shouldn't it also generate the correct output?

Comment: you are right but please give a it a try, move your project to under xampp, as I am saw phpmyadmin has been setup like this by defualt installation of XAMPP

Comment: Ok, so I moved the project folder and restarted XAMPP, I still see the same weirdly-rendered page as when the site was in a sub-folder.

Comment: Sorry, when I said XAMPP, I meant Apache & it's running on port 80

Comment: your wordpress project is in htdocs how did you installed that

Comment: I've always just added sub-folders in htdocs so each site would be it's own subfolder e.g. c:\xampp\htdocs\site1\ would be http://localhost/site1

This is how all my projects current are, except that one which is custom code is different. It could be the code but then why does it work perfectly on two separate linux web servers but not on windows?

Comment: plz join this chat room lets dig this out why many ppl having issue for XAMPP in windows http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134980/xammpp-windows7-issue